# Are array indexes 0-based in VB6?

Tags: arrays, vb6, vb6-migration

I'm reviewing an automatic translation of VB6 code to C# and the convertor translated `someArray(3)` to `someArray[3]`. But accordingly to the old code documentation it should pick the third element not the fourth as it is doing in the translated version.

Are array indexes 0-based in VB6? Or do they start at 1?

Comment: Is this an array *declaration* or accessing an array *element*?

Comment: @Cody Accessing an array element.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes - arrays are (generally) 0 based in VB6

The exceptions to this are when the explicit `Dim someArray(1 To 10) as Int` syntax has been used, or when `Option Base 1` is declared at the top of the code module.

It's `Collections` that aren't - when you loop through `Collection` objects I'm pretty sure that they are 1 based.

Comment: "Unless Explicit Type Syntax has been used" *Or* `Option Base 1` has been declared at the top of the code block

Comment: @Matt Does this statement affect only the current file?

Comment: @XMLforDummies: Yes - in VB6 you have the `Option` statements at the top of each code file.

Comment: @XMLforDummies - Yes, so if say you have two modules and ModuleA has Option Base 1 declared then any array declared in ModuleA is 1 based.

Comment: Unless explicitly specified otherwise at the moment of array declaration. It gets complicated. That's one of the reasons why they changed this for VB.NET.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is that array lower bounds are what you *tell* them to be.

The *default* is base `0` (unless overridden by `Option Base 1`), but you can declare lower bound to any value you want (`Dim arr(-42 To 42)` is as valid as `Dim(3)`).

Also, if an array is returned by some object, its lower bound is whatever that object sets it to.  For example an `Excel` `Range.Value` reference will return a `1` based array.